# Azure managed identity Arc enabled server and operator security

Tags: azure, network-security

I have an Arc enabled server which is using managed identity to connect to an Azure Key Vault.  The IIS hosted application is able to access the key vault without any problems, but there's a security element which could be a security risk.

If an operator logs onto the machine, would they be able to access the key vault, as the server as a whole has the managed identity, so they could in theory run powershell commands to query the key vault as they are in machine context?

Comment: What kind of permissions does the operator logon with?

Comment: They will run patches and perform maintenance of the server, so I guess admininistrators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operator has the ability to access the terminal and to install either the Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell (or it is already there), then they can use this to log in to Azure with the managed identity and access the Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

If an operator has local access to the machine and sufficient permissions, they could potentially use the managed identity context to run PowerShell commands or other tools to interact with Azure Key Vault.

Comment: It does seem a bit of a problem, as operators wanting to patch the servers would have login permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update incase anyone else has this scenario.

We put an app service infront of the keyvault, the appservice is locked by IP (using NSG), and uses certificate authentication. The certificate is embedded in source.

So if the operator is able to access the keyvault, it won't be by accident.